# best way to backup & restore user data?

Tags: android

I am writing an android training app.
It should have a feature enabling the user to backup his results ( string of text ), but I am not sure what would be the best way.
I do not want to set up a dedicated server for that purpose. I already made the app generate a text file and suggest the user to email it to himself.
But what would be the best way of retrieving it? Just tell the user to save it in some Download folder and than select it from the app? In that case the app would need permissions to access storage that might discourage some users...

Comment: Have you considered Android's recommendations? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup

Comment: Thank you, will take a look into it.

Comment: If you target API 30 (min API 19) I would recommend using shared storage and save your text file to the documents directory which don't need file permissions to read and write. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files